# Java Headless exception

Tags: java, gwt, awt, headless

I am working with `GWT 2.8.2` and I am trying to start `GWT` in dev mode by invoking the main of `com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode` in a `Linux Server`.

I got the following exception when the `-Djava.awt.headless` property was set to `false`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0                                                                                        .0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java                                                                                        :65)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:110)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:7                                                                                        4)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvi                                                                                        ronment.java:81)
        at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:120)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:869)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:861)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1256)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.SwingUI.invokeAndWait(SwingUI.java:407)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.SwingUI.initialize(SwingUI.java:249)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.doStartup(DevModeBase.java:783)
```

I worked around the first problem by setting the `-Djava.awt.headless=true` but then I ended up with the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:224)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.SwingUI$3.run(SwingUI.java:258)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:302)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:738)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:708)
```

I have also tried to export the DISPLAY variable, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Are you actually running a display there? If not, exporting DISPLAY won't have any effect.

Comment: Why are you running DevMode in a server instead of the dev environment?